# Brownian Motion as a Limit of Simpler Models

Tags: brownian-motion

Let $Δ$ be a small increment of time, and consider a process such that every $Δ$ time units the value of the process either increases by the amount $σ \cdot sqrt(Δ)$ with probability $p$ or decreases by the amount $σ \cdot sqrt(Δ)$ with probability $1-p$, where:

$p = \frac{1}{2}[1+(μ/σ)*sqrt(Δ)]$

This is taken from Chapter 3 in "Elementary Introduction to Mathematical Finance" by Sheldon Ross. Although I can follow the exposition throughout the rest of the chapter, I fail to understand why the above formula is defined the way it is.

I would greatly appreciate a resource or explanation to help me intuitively understand this.

Comment: Yes, there is. Thanks for pointing it out! I edited it.

Comment: As explained below this formula for $p$ was cleverly chosen so the expected change is proportional to the elapsed time $\Delta$ and the variance of the change is also proportional to $\Delta$, two properties that characterize Brownian Motion With Drift. This you can verify by computing these two statistics, E and V.

Answer (score 2):

The general idea is that we want to connect the binomial model to Geometric Brownian Motion. A binomial model for stock price movements assume that, in a small time increment $\Delta$, price and either increase with a probability of $p$ or decrease with a probability of $1-p$.

Geometric Brownian Motion (GBM) is a continuous-time stochastic processes used to model stock price. The general parameters are $\mu$ for the drift, and $\sigma$ for the volatility.

In order to connect the binomial model to GBM, we need to ensure that over a large number of steps, the binomial model converges to GBM. This is simply done by matching the mean and variance.

If we match the mean, in the binomial model, the return after a small time $\Delta$, the expected return for an up-move is $p\sigma \sqrt{\Delta}$, and for a down-move $(1-p)\sigma \sqrt{\Delta}$. The expected return for GBM is $\Delta\mu$. Thus, we have
$$p\sigma \sqrt{\Delta} - (1-p)\sigma\sqrt{\Delta} = \Delta \mu$$

If we solve the above equation for $p$, we get the desired formula
$$
p=\frac{1}{2}(1+\frac{\mu}{\sigma}\sqrt{\Delta})
$$
For the intuition behind it, is that the resulting value of $p$ will ensure that both the mean and variance of the binomial model match that of the GBM over small time increments.

If you want to read more about it, I would say reading about stochastic processes and understanding how to model stock price using GBM is important.

Comment: Excellent answer! Thank you very much!